# Trying to whitelist variables in PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to check if the variables I'm getting from ajax are what I expect or if someone is trying to inject some nasty stuff.

There are basically two things I need to check...that the $sortvalue is one of two possible options AND that the $sortorder is one of two possible options. This needs to be an OR / AND statement. Like this:

Check 1: If $sortvalue is either "value" OR "database_percent"
AND
Check 2: If $sortorder is either "asc" OR "desc"

Then go ahead with the rest of the code.

I have the below in my PHP, and the $sortvalue part works, but the $sortorder doesn't. That is, if I try to send a value other than "asc" or "desc" for $sortorder, I get a 500 error. I guess I'm not quite sure how to nest these together.

```
if ($sortvalue == "value" || $sortvalue == "database_percent" && $sortorder == "asc" || $sortorder == "desc") {
//do something
}
else {
//do something different
}
```

Comment: Add parens. `&&` takes precedence over `||` conditions.

Comment: Or use `in_array($sortvalue, [ 'value', 'database_percent' ])`. This makes it easier to add more terms if needed in the future.

Comment: @Phylogenesis I'd like to get this working, as I do have a lot more terms in some other files. I'm getting 500 errors though. Should it be like this:

`if (
 in_array($sortvalue, [ 'value', 'database_percent' ])
 && 
 in_array($sortorder, [ 'asc', 'desc' ])
)`

Comment: @jonmrich: Yes. Depending on the version of PHP you have, it might be `in_array($sortvalue, array('value', 'database_percent'))`. The square bracket notation is from [PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: @Phylogenesis Yes...that was it. Needed the version above. Which PHP version is this for? I thought I was on 5.4

Comment: That was the problem. Apparently I'm on PHP 5.3.29.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use parenthesis to enforce operator precedence:

```
if (
     ($sortvalue == "value" || $sortvalue == "database_percent") 
     && 
     ($sortorder == "asc" || $sortorder == "desc")
   ) {
//do something
}
else {
//do something different
}
```

Comment: It's also worthwhile to note that the parentheses define separate *expressions*, so effectively you're doing `expression1 && expression2`.